# How do I get the matching values inside a for loop using FILTER in PIG?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Consider this as my input,

```
Input (File1):
12345;11
34567;12
.
.

Input (File2):
11;(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
12;(9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1)
.
.
```

I would like to get the output as follows:

```
Output:
(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
(9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1)
```

Here's the sample code which I have tried using FILTER and I face some errors with this. Please suggest me some other options.

```
data1 = load '/File1' using PigStorage(';') as (id,number);
data2 = load '/File2' using PigStorage(';') as (numberInfo, collection);

out = foreach data1{
Data_filter = FILTER data2 by (numberInfo matches CONCAT(number,''));
generate Data_filter;
}
```

Is it possible do this inside a for loop ? Please let me know. Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

There are no for loops in Apache Pig, if you need to iterate through each row of the data for some specific purpose you need to implement your own UDF. The `foreach` keyword is not used to create a loop, it is used to transform your data based on your columns, applying UDFs to it. You can also use a nested `foreach`, where you perform operations over each group in your relation.

However, your syntax is wrong. You are trying to use a nested foreach without grouping your data first. What a nested foreach does, is perform the operations you define in the block of code over a *grouped relation*. Therefore, the only way your code could work is by grouping the data first:

```
data1 = load '/File1' using PigStorage(';') as (id,number);
data2 = load '/File2' using PigStorage(';') as (numberInfo, collection);

data1 = group data1 by id;

out = foreach data1{
    Data_filter = FILTER data2 by (numberInfo matches CONCAT(number,''));
    generate Data_filter;
}
```

However, this won't work because inside a nested `foreach` you cannot refer to a different relation like `data2`.

What you really want, is a `JOIN` operation over both relations using `number` for `data1` and `numberInfo` for `data2`. This will give you this:

```
joined_data = join data1 by number, data2 by numberInfo;

dump joined_data;
(12345,11,11,(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9))
(34567,12,12,(9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1))
```

In your question you said you only wanted as output the last column, so now you can use a `foreach` to generate the column you want:

```
final_data = foreach joined_data generate data2::collection;

dump final_data;
((1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9))
((9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1))
```